# Why isn't the second browser updating the location of my images?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, mean-stack

I made a checkers game for a class project. I want to be able to play it with other people using socket.io, but for some reason the images are not updating on the second browser.

server.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 console.log("Working now?");
 socket.broadcast.emit('update_position', lastPosition);
 socket.on('receive_position', function (data) {
 lastPosition = data;
 socket.broadcast.emit('update_position', data);
}); 
});
```

index.ejs

```
    <script>

    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var socket = io.connect();
      console.log("Hello");
      socket.on('update_position', function (data) {
        $(data.id).css('left', data.x);
        $(data.id).css('top', data.y);
        var x = data.x;
        var y = data.y;
        console.log(data);
        // jquery code to move div here
      });
      $(".drag").draggable().click(function () {
        var coord = $(this).offset();
        $("#left").val(coord.left);
        $("#top").val(coord.top);
        console.log(coord);
        socket.emit('receive_position', { x: coord.left, y: coord.top, id: 
  this.id });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I am also receiving this error whenever I click and hold on the images. However, I am eventually able to move the images and place them on the board.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined

Comment: None of the code you provide contains `setData`. As such, it's impossible to identify why that is causing a problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the code.